# Viewport or innerHeight of Amazons Kindle Fire?

Tags: resolution, viewport, kindle-fire, amazon-silk

I build a webpage for the iPad and now I need to make some adjustments to get it run on the Kindle Fire. The main problem is, I cant't find any informations about the real usable space in the silk browser. On many sites on the net they say it's 1024x600. But that can't be true, because of the statusbar, adressbar, etc. - Im kinda lost here!

Kind regards,
Markus

Comment: Is there any solution to this? Kindle Fire 1st Gen and the iPads all are 1024 px in width, but with Kindle, a webpage with 1024px doesn't fit. The screen width is less than the webpage for Kindle.

Answer (score 0):

Using http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/ on the kindle fire, it's reporting the viewport size as 1024x395